# Proving an alternative version of Lallement's Lemma

Tags: semigroups, semigroup-homomorphism

> Let $\phi:S\rightarrow T$ be a (homo)morphism from a regular semigroup
>   $S$ into a semigroup $T$. Then $\textrm{im}(\phi)$ is regular. If $f$
>   is an idempotent in $\textrm{im}(\phi)$ then there exists an
>   idempotent $e\in S$ such that $e\phi=f$.

This is stated without proof on page 57 of J.M. Howie's *Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory*.

**Attempt at a proof:**  Since $S$ is regular, we know that $\forall x\in S, \ \exists y\in S$ such that $x=xyx$. Thus, using the fact that $\phi$ is a homomorphism: $$x\phi=(xyx)\phi=(x\phi)(y\phi)(x\phi).$$
So, $\textrm{im}(\phi)$ is regular since $\forall\ x\phi\ \exists\ y\phi\in\textrm{im}(\phi)$ so that $x\phi=x\phi y\phi x\phi$.

$\textrm{im}(\phi)=\lbrace x\phi\ \mid\ x\in S\rbrace.$ If $f$ is an idempotent element of $\textrm{im}(\phi)$ then $f=x\phi$ such that $f^2=(x\phi)^2=(x\phi)(x\phi)=x^2\phi=x\phi=f$. Therefore, let $x=e\in E_{S}$.

I'm not sure if this is correct. I feel like I've bodged it a little bit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can you assume that $x = e$ for some idempotent $e$ of $S$ ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1200784/ for a correct proof (using inverses, not pseudoinverses).

Comment: @darijgrinberg I don't know, that's why I'm asking. If $f=x\phi$ is an idempotent element of $\textrm{im}(\phi)$ then does it not follow that $x\in E_{S}$?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The canonical projection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ sends $3$ to the idempotent $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/2$, but this doesn't mean that $3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an idempotent.

Comment: I'm still unsure how to proceed; I've shown that if $f=x\phi$ then $f^2=(x\phi)^{2}=(x\phi y\phi x\phi)(x\phi y\phi x\phi)=x\phi y\phi(x\phi x\phi)y\phi x\phi=x\phi y\phi (x\phi) y\phi x\phi = (xyx)\phi y\phi x\phi =x\phi y\phi x\phi=x\phi=f$ but that doesn't give us anything new

Answer (score 1):

First, every $x$ has an *inverse* $y$, satisfying both $xyx=x$ and $yxy=y$.
(It follows from $xtx=x\,$ by taking $\,y:=txt$.)

Now, suppose $x^\phi=f=f^2$, and consider an inverse $y\ $ **for** $\underline{x^2}$, and set also $g:=y^\phi$. Then
$$e:=xyx$$
is an idempotent: $e^2=xyx^2yx=xyx=e$ with image $f$:
$$e^\phi=(xyx)^\phi=fgf=f^2gf^2=(x^2yx^2)^\phi=(x^2)^\phi=f\,.$$